# Swift: cannot preload Coredata

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data, swift, xcode6

When I include a SQLite file with Objective-C under "Target - Build Phases - Copy Bundle Resources", this file will be completely copied to the target, i.e. device or simulator. On the target, I get the whole file: tables and contents (Records/rows).

Doing the same with Swift, the tables will be copied, but they are empty: no records/rows. :-(

Can I do something additional? Is there any "trick"?

How can I preload my core data with base-records using Swift???

I'm using Xcode v6.1.1, with Beta 6.2 it is the same.

Comment: Copying the resource file to the target is done by Xcode, not by Objectice-C or Swift.

Comment: Might be due to iOS using a different SQLite pragma, with the result that the db is stored in three files: .sqlite, .sqlite-shm and .sqlite-wal.  Either copy the -shm and -wal files as well, or change the pragma when you create the db.

Comment: Ok, Martin i agree. But it doesnt help me

Comment: @ pbasdf: copying .sqlite-shm and .sqlite-wal doesnt change anything. :-( How can i change the pragma???

Comment: You can change pragmas with the `NSSQLitePragmasOption`. But before doing so, set Core Data to verbose mode and check the used pragmas.

Comment: @MartinR UlliHeinelt said that the files are copied, but empty. Ulli, how did you check that? From your app code or with a SQL tool? What about file size?

Comment: As per @AminNegm-Awad, use NSSQLitePragmasOption - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19982830/3985749) for further info.

Comment: The -shm and -wal files are optimizations created at runtime and needn't (shouldn't) be copied.

Comment: I bet it's something more obvious, like you've mistyped the filename somewhere or you're looking for it in the wrong directory.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: can u please give me a sample how and where to set NSSQLitePragmasOption in Swift? I cannot find anything about this in Swift, but i'm an absolute Swift-NewBy. :-( I use the Standard-Swift-Template

Comment: @UlliHeinelt No, I cannot, because writing swift code bringt me pimples with pus to my ass.

Comment: @MartinR: i checked it from the app code and two SQLite-tools

Comment: @pbasdf and all: can u please give me a sample how and where to set NSSQLitePragmasOption in Swift?

Comment: This is specified when building the CoreData stack, specifically when you add a NSPersistentStore to the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.  If you are using Apple's template, this is usually done in the AppDelegate.  Locate the code which lazy-loads the persistent store coordinator.  There should be a function call to `addPersistentStoreWithType`.  One of the arguments is `options:` - you add the NSSQLitePragmasOption to that argument. (eg. ...options:[NSSQLitePragmasOption : ["journal_mode" : "DELETE"]])

Comment: @pbasdf: THX, but that doesn't change anything :-( It's driving me crazy...

Comment: @UlliHeinelt How do you create the original sqlite file?  In Objective-C, or Swift?

Comment: @pbasdf i created it in Objective-C...

Comment: OK.  Thinking aloud now... If it is an issue with the -wal file, you need to specify the NSSQLitePragmasOption in the Objective-C that creates the sqlite database.  But if you can read the data OK (without the -wal file) from Objective-C, then the -wal file is not the problem.  Have you tried any of the logic from David's answer below - i.e. using NSFileManager to check existence of the file?  Can you post the function which lazy-loads the persistent store coordinator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69147/discussion-between-ulliheinelt-and-pbasdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my solution (for sqlite-files). I don't know why it is so "extravagant" in Swift. Perhaps there's an easier way?
**Many THX to pbasdf**!!!

**Important**: beneath the *.sqlite-file you must add the *.sqlite-shm and the *.sqlite-wal to your project 
This files will automatically be added to "Target - Build Phases - Copy Bundle Resources"

This is based on the **Standard-Template for the "AppDelegate.swift"**…

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

    let dataName = „MyData.sqlite" // must be replaced by the name of your file!
    let modelName = „MyData“ // must be replaced by the name of your model!

    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(dataName)

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let fromURL = bundle.URLForResource(modelName, withExtension: "sqlite")

    // check sqlite-file: must it be installed?
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(url.path!) {
        self.copySqlliteFiles(modelName, databaseName: dataName)
    }

    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options:  nil, error: &error) == nil {
```

...}

```
   return coordinator
}()

// MARK: - copy sqllite-files (c) by Ray Wenderlich & Team in „“Core Data by Tutorials“

// check sqlite-files: they must be installed...
func copySqlliteFiles(modelName: String, databaseName: String)
{
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()

    let baseDatabaseURL = bundle.URLForResource(modelName, withExtension: "sqlite")
    let documentsURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory
    let storeURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(databaseName)
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(baseDatabaseURL!, toURL: storeURL,error: nil)

    let baseSHMURL = bundle.URLForResource(modelName,withExtension: "sqlite-shm")
    let shmURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(databaseName + "-shm")
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(baseSHMURL!, toURL: shmURL, error: nil)

    let walURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(databaseName + "-wal")
    let baseWALURL = bundle.URLForResource(modelName, withExtension: "sqlite-wal")
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(baseWALURL!, toURL: walURL, error: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this probably has to do with how files are laid out on iOS.  Specifically:

1. when you copy the source file (by Xcode or at install time) it gets placed into the application bundle/container directory (which is read-only)
2. The standard CoreData initialization code looks for the data store in the Documents directory.
3. Not finding your source data (because it's in the wrong place), CoreData creates a new empty store.

To fix this, you need to copy the store from the Application directory to the Documents directory if it doesn't already exist.

This [link](http://www.g8production.com/post/40258880359/coredata-how-preload-data-in-ios) gives an explanation and example code to do that.  But in Objective-C it looks like:

```
NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] 
    stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyDB.sqlite"];
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];

// Copy the default db if it doesn't already exist
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
    NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
        pathForResource:@"MyDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    if (defaultStorePath) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath 
toPath:storePath error:NULL];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry David, i don't need an Objetive-C-Suppert, cause with Objetive-C all is fine... And the sqlite-file is written in the Documents directory

Answer (score 0):

I had a related issue related to this.  I started working on some tutorials which used this line:

```
documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("StoreName")
```

At some point this stopped working.  Data was not being written to the store anymore.  To see why data was not being written, I tried opening the sqlite file but could not find it on my mac at the URL being used.  The app folder was there, but there was no sqlite file.  I looked back at older core data projects and found they used .sqlite extension.  So I modified the line to:

```
documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("StoreName.sqlite")
```

This seemed to work so give it a try.