# fetchRequest.predicate with Coredata runs fine with Objective-C but not with swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data

I have two entities with relationships in coredata:

Entity "Kategorien" has the relation "To Many" to Entity "Details" that is called "kategorie"

[image]

In controllerA with "Kategorien" i pick "Kategorien" and reach it to the controller "DetailViewController" with "Details":

**Swift:**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MainDetail" {
        let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
        let kat:Kategorien = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Kategorien

        controller.kategorie = kat        }
}
```

In DetailViewController i receive it:

```
class DetailViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var kategoie:Kategorien!
```

In **Objective-C** kat is a property in DetailViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Kategorien *kat;
```

and in the fetchResulController i just said

```
#pragma mark - Fetched results controllers delegates
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
...
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kategorie == %@", kat];
```

and the records for the kategorie are shown.

With **Swift** in the fetchResulController i tried it with

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"kategorie == %@", kategorie)
```

and other ways (i.e. kategorie.description) but

**no records will appear**

Whar did i missunderstand? Where is my mistake? It drives me **crazy**...

Comment: Why is it `kategorie` in the creation of the Swift predicate and `kat` in Objective-C? – (If you provide a *link* to a screenshot of your Core Data model then a friendly user might add it to your question :)

Comment: Sorry: kategorie is in Swift and kat in Objective-C. I both means the same. How can i provide a link???

Comment: You could for example upload the image to http://imgur.com and post the link here.

Comment: If the property is called `kategory` in the Swift code, then why do you have `var kat:Kategorien!` and not `var kategory:Kategorien!` ?

Comment: shit, there stands:     var kategorie:Kategorien!
That's right. Copy & Paste Error :-)

Comment: It would really be helpful (and save your and our time) if you copy/paste your *real code*: now you have `var kategoie:Kategorien!` which must be a typo again. – That being said, I cannot see a difference between the ObjC and the Swift predicate, both should work, I assume that the problem is somewhere else. What happens if you don't assign a predicate: Do you get all objects?

Comment: @ Martin R: if i don't assign a predicate i also see no records...

Comment: Well, that means that the problem is unrelated to the predicate and there must be something else :)

Comment: @ Martin R SORRY! I know it's the sabsolute wrong place here for this question, but i don't know how to get help :-( i've recogniced, that you see it, then i add a comment or answer to a question. How can i do that? I found nothing in the help...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. If you have new information about the problem then you can edit and update your question.

Comment: but u always give quick reply! How do u do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it! :-)
Took a solution from Ray Wenderlichs "Core Data by Tutorials" to manage the MOC:

```
import CoreData
public class CoreDataStack {  
  let context:NSManagedObjectContext
  let psc:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
  let model:NSManagedObjectModel
  let store:NSPersistentStore?
  ...
```

This class is called by AppDelegate.swift (no MOC...) and the ViewControllers. But this allways creates a new MOC! So "Kategorien" and "Details" have own MOCs.
So the fetchRequest

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kategorie == %@", kategorie]
```

in Details has another MOC as kategorien got from controllerA.

Now i killed the class CoreDataStack and ported all to AppDelegate.swift see [Swift: cannot preload Coredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841095/swift-cannot-preload-coredata). Now all use the same MOC and everything is fine... :-)

Answer (score 2):

That constructor is not available in swift, since it uses varargs.

Instead of the Objective C constructor:

```
+ (NSPredicate *)predicateWithFormat:(NSString *)format
```

use the swift constructor:

```
init(format predicateFormat: String, 
     argumentArray arguments: [AnyObject]?) -> NSPredicate
```

So your code should look like:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"kategorie == %@", argumentArray:[kategorie])
```

Comment: THX Alex, but i get the errormessage "extraneous argument label "arguments" in call". May you help???

Comment: Try the new version.  If in doubt, cmd-click on the symbol NSPredicate in Xcode to see the actual API. !code completion is also your friend.

Comment: yes, i did it this way, but still get no Child-Records (???) Could it be, that the cause is, that i use a sqlite-file migrated from the Objective-C-Version????

Comment: @AlexBrown: Your statement is not correct. `NSPredicate(format:"kategorie == %@", kategorie)` works just fine in Swift. You find it as `convenience init?(format predicateFormat: String, _ args: CVarArgType...)` in the API.

Comment: (lldb) po  fetchRequest.predicate say and this is fine:
kategorie == <Visitenkarten.Kategorien: 0x79c2b670> (entity: Kategorien; id: 0x79c2a570 <x-coredata://91D8713F-5CDA-4012-9C8A-C552EF4AB19F/Kategorien/p1> ; data: {
    columns = "<relationship fault: 0x7991a5e0 'columns'>";
    details = "<relationship fault: 0x7991a9d0 'details'>";
    katid = 1;
    name = "\U00c4rzte/Therapeuten";
    order = 0;
})